# Java-Convert FileTime to Date Format

Tags: java

i want to convert filetime to date in format(DD/MM/YYYY).

here is my code.

```
Path path = Paths.get(FilePath);
            BasicFileAttributes attr;
             attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
             FileTime date=attr.creationTime();
             DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
             Fdate=df.format(date.toMillis());
```

i tried this code month and year is working fine and it's in the format but some value is printing in the day(DD). 
Thank you.

Comment: JavaDoc on `SimpleDateFormat`(you should read it eventually): "D - Day in year, example: 189.".

Answer (score 3):

You have to use lower d and lower y:

```
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Because:

> D  Day in year
>   d  Day in month
>   y  Year
>   Y  Week year

For more informations see the [javadoc of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I'd add a small paragraph on the week year (since it might not be that clear): if the week that Jan 1st falls into is considered to be the last calendar week of the previous year the week year would not be the new year but the previous one. As an example the week year for Jan 1st to Jan 3rd 2016 would be 2015.

Comment: @Rajkumar if it works, feel free to accept my answer